# How to implement Google Places API in React JS?

Tags: reactjs, google-places-api

I'm trying to implement Google Places API in React JS, but I am not able to do that, I don't know where I have to start, I was looking for some libraries, but everything that I get is about Google Maps, and those are 2 different APIs.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not provide much details but I think this tutorial may fits your needs, check it out:

[Google Maps React Component](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/how-to-write-a-google-maps-react-component/)

The entire module is available at [google-maps-react](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react) 
as indicated in the tutorial. 
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [react-google-location](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-location) npm package. it provide everything that you need such as **current location,coordinates and google places also**.

Comment: That package appears to not be maintained.