# How to load the Google Places API in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api

I want to use Google Maps and Places API in my React application for users to be able get hospitals in their area on the map.

I am using both @react-google-maps/api and use-places-autocomplete npm packages to interface with the API to display the map and places. I am using the useLoadScript hook to load in my API key and also declare libraries I will be using.

In this case, just as I have enabled Places and Maps JavaScript APIs, I supplied *places* in the libraries array.

[image: Google Maps Places API library must be loaded]

I have tried adding the below script to the index.html file:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

but I get the error: You are loading the map multiple times.

Here's a snippet of my code where I use the useLoadScript hook from the @react-google-maps/api
[image: useLoadScript code]

Please how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51505877/how-to-implement-google-places-api-in-react-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using `useLoadScript` of the `@react-google-maps/api library` and `use-places-autocomplete` you need to supply the ['places'] as a value of your library to use the Places Autocomplete in your code. Please note that this `useLoadScript` will load the Google Maps JavaScript Script tag in your code and you don't need to add the script tag in the html file anymore.

From what I understand, your use case where the user will select a place from the autocomplete dropdown and the nearest hospital should be returned in the map.

To achieve this, you need to have this flow:

1. Use `use-places-autocomplete` to provide place suggestion when searching for a place. This library have a `GetGeocode` and a [`GetLatLng`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-places-autocomplete#getlatlng) that you can use to get the coordinates of the chosen place.
2. Once you have the coordinates, you can use [Places API Nearby Search](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests), use the keyword `hospital` in your request and define a radius. This will search a list of hospital within the defined radius with the chosen place as the center.
3. You can loop through the list of result and pin each coordinates as markers in your map.

Here;s the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/atreact-google-mapsapi-with-useplaceautocomplete-cpmdv4?file=Map.js) and a code snippet below. Make sure to add your API Key:

Index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Map from "./Map";

render(<Map />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Map.js

```
/*global google*/
import React from "react";
import { GoogleMap, useLoadScript } from "@react-google-maps/api";
import Search from "./Search";

let service;
const libraries = ["places"];

const mapContainerStyle = {
  height: "100vh",
  width: "100vw"
};
const options = {
  disableDefaultUI: true,
  zoomControl: true
};
const center = {
  lat: 43.6532,
  lng: -79.3832
};

export default function App() {
  const { isLoaded, loadError } = useLoadScript({
    googleMapsApiKey: "YOUR_API_KEY",
    libraries
  });
  const mapRef = React.useRef();
  const onMapLoad = React.useCallback(map => {
    mapRef.current = map;
  }, []);

  const panTo = React.useCallback(({ lat, lng }) => {
    mapRef.current.panTo({ lat, lng });
    mapRef.current.setZoom(12);
    let map = mapRef.current;

    let request = {
      location: { lat, lng },
      radius: "500",
      type: ["hospital"]
    };

    service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(mapRef.current);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    function callback(results, status) {
      if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
          let place = results[i];
          new google.maps.Marker({
            position: place.geometry.location,
            map
          });
        }
      }
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <Search panTo={panTo} />
      <GoogleMap
        id="map"
        mapContainerStyle={mapContainerStyle}
        zoom={8}
        center={center}
        options={options}
        onLoad={onMapLoad}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Search.js

```
import React from "react";
import usePlacesAutocomplete, {
  getGeocode,
  getLatLng
} from "use-places-autocomplete";

export default function Search({ panTo }) {
  const {
    ready,
    value,
    suggestions: { status, data },
    setValue,
    clearSuggestions
  } = usePlacesAutocomplete({
    requestOptions: {
      /* Define search scope here */
    },
    debounce: 300
  });

  const handleInput = e => {
    // Update the keyword of the input element
    setValue(e.target.value);
  };

  const handleSelect = ({ description }) => () => {
    // When user selects a place, we can replace the keyword without request data from API
    // by setting the second parameter to "false"
    setValue(description, false);
    clearSuggestions();

    // Get latitude and longitude via utility functions
    getGeocode({ address: description })
      .then(results => getLatLng(results[0]))
      .then(({ lat, lng }) => {
        panTo({ lat, lng });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(" Error: ", error);
      });
  };

  const renderSuggestions = () =>
    data.map(suggestion => {
      const {
        place_id,
        structured_formatting: { main_text, secondary_text }
      } = suggestion;

      return (
        <li key={place_id} onClick={handleSelect(suggestion)}>
          <strong>{main_text}</strong> <small>{secondary_text}</small>
        </li>
      );
    });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        value={value}
        onChange={handleInput}
        disabled={!ready}
        placeholder="Where are you going?"
      />
      {/* We can use the "status" to decide whether we should display the dropdown or not */}
      {status === "OK" && <ul>{renderSuggestions()}</ul>}
    </div>
  );
}
```